# Typescript CI/CD post type errors to github pr

Tags: typescript, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

Pronto can be used with ESLint/typescript plugins to lint code and post lint errors to Github PRs, but is there a means of type checking .ts files on a PR and then posting errors as Github comments?